# How can i send OTP to users phone number in Laravel

Tags: laravel, gupshup

I have gupshup account. i want to create api in laravel which will send otp to phone using gupshup account.i am new at laravel

Answer (score 0):

As per GupShup API docs for [Outbound Messages](https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/whatsapp-api-documentation#OutboundMessage) you will need to make a post request to their server with your API key and information.

Laravel uses Guzzle [HTTP client](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#introduction) to make requests. You can make post requests using the `HTTP` facade. An untested example is below:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http; // To be added to the top of your file where you add the code below

// Put the following code in the function which sends out the OTP.
$response = Http::withHeaders([
                  "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                  "apikey": "{{Your API Key}}" // replace with your API key
                   ])
                  ->post('https://api.gupshup.io/sm/api/v1/msg',
                       [
                       "channel" => "whatsapp",
                       "source" => "1111111111", // your business number
                       "destination" => "9999999999", // clients number
                       "src.name" => "Your App" // Your App Name
                       "message" => [
                             "isHSM" => "false",
                             "type" => "text",
                             "text" => "{{Your OTP is XXXXX}}" // replace with text you want to send
                         ] 
                       ]
                      );
```